# Is it possible to have different express middleware for different handlers in the same route path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to have different routes under an `/api` path with different middleware handlers. Specifically different API routes should allow different ways of authenticating.

I thought I could nest different API routes under two different `Router`s with different middleware:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

const one = express.Router();
one.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("one");
  next();
});
one.get("/api/one", (req, res) => {
  console.log("/api/one");
  res.send("one");
});

// ---

const two = express.Router();
two.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("two");
  next();
});
two.get("/api/two", (req, res) => {
  console.log("/api/two");
  res.send("two");
});

// ---

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
app.use(one);
app.use(two);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I would expect that `one` would get logged when navigating to `/api/one` and `two` gets logged when navigating to `/api/two`, however *both* middlewares get run when navigating to `/api/two`:

```
Example app listening on port 4000
one
/api/one
one
two
/api/two
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for **without** listing the different middleware for each individual API route?

Comment: What do you mean by "*without listing the different middleware for each individual API route*"? How many individual API routes do you have, and where do they live? In your example, it's not really clear why you are using the two routers at all.

Comment: You can easily put middleware on a particular path.  You can easily put middleware on one or more routes individually.  But, if you have 6 routes on the same path on the same router, there is no way to have 3 of the routes on one middleware and three on the other middleware without just specifying the appropriate middleware on each of the 6 routes.  The designed solution for this is to put each 3 routes on a different path where you can more easily specific the middleware once for each 3 routes.

Comment: Routers don't encapsulate context. Therefore if `next()` is called it will simply continue processing the middleware stack. You have a very wrong understanding of how Express work. Express is best thought of as a one dimensional stack/array of handlers (middlewares) that get executed one after another. If you want a middleware to only execute on a specific path you need to define it on that path (eg: `one.use('/api/one', middleware)`). Express will not apply a path rule for a latter handler to a handler defined previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the simple answer is no.

You cannot have different middleware handlers for routes that are part of the same path. Middleware is not encapsulated withing a single `Router`, and so using two different `Router`s on the same path with different middleware will result in middleware on the first router running on routes defined in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Both your routers, and with that all their middlewares, are bound to the root path. I suspect what you actually wanted is to place the whole router under a specific route:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

const one = express.Router();
one.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("one");
  next();
});
one.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.path + " from router 1");
  res.send("one");
});

// ---

const two = express.Router();
two.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("two");
  next();
});
two.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.path + " from router 2");
  res.send("two");
});

// ---

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
app.use("/api/one", one);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^
app.use("/api/two", two);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of here is to use different path prefixes, the router middleware will only get triggered for the specific route prefix.

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

const one = express.Router();
one.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("one");
  next();
});
one.get("/one", (req, res) => {
  console.log("/api/one");
  res.send("one");
});

const two = express.Router();
two.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("two");
  next();
});
two.get("/two", (req, res) => {
  console.log("/api/two");
  res.send("two");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

// Different prefix
app.use("/api1", one);
app.use("/api2", two);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I cannot change the path

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t think there is another way, express doesn’t know which router will handle the request, it acts like filter.